# Is it possible to assign a JSON value inside a YAML definition?

Tags: json, yaml, snakeyaml

For my domain object I would like to be able to assign a JSON literal to a key when using yaml, more specifically snakeyaml. Here is what I would be able to use:

```
ContentType(teaser):
    name: teaser
    json: { "foo": "bar", \
          "acme": "co..." } \
```

Is this possible at all, and how?

PS: For the example above Snakeyaml (used inside Play! Framework test case) answers with
YAMLException has been caught, null; mapping values are not allowed here

Answer (score 0):

Your 'json' property must be a Map

Ask in the SnakeYAML mailing list providing a test case.